# Как узнать КПД участника?

Tags: обсуждение, репутация, профиль-участника

В карточке пользователя, помимо его имени, имеются также баллы репутации и значки. Баллы репутации начисляются не только за вопросы и в связи с этим вопрос:
можно ли добавить к карточке пользователя или каким-либо другим способом узнать соотношение всех ответов пользователя к принятым ответам, за вычетом репутации начисленной не за ответы пользователя?

Comment: Можно через API узнать сколько репутации за ответы: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-on-users Брать только те, где `"post_type": "answer"`

Comment: На dataSE можно написать sql-запрос.

Comment: Но к сожалению, это не покажет всей картины в целом, так как очень часто отличные ответы не принимают, так как не у всех участников сообщества есть полное понимание зачем это надо и они игнорируют данную функцию. Есть очень много заплюсованных ответов, но так и не принятых :(

Comment: @L.F.C. а еще есть отличные ответы, которые, к сожалению, участники сообщества вообще не могут оценить по достоинству.

Comment: Другими словами - без танцев с бубном не обойтись. @АндрейNOP ничего там не понял, то ли лыжи не едут, то ли я... не далёкий. Насколько я понял, там можно сконструировать API запрос и он будет выглядеть в виде URL. Если так, то не смогли бы Вы его создать?

Comment: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/182750/reputation?page=1&pagesize=100&site=ru.stackoverflow page меняйте, чтобы получить следующую порцию

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### Через поиск

Количество принятых ответов для заданного участника можно определить через поиск. Для этого в поиск нужно вбить следующий запрос:

```
user:%USERID% is:a isaccepted:1
```

где %USERID% — ID участника, которое отображается в URL профиля. При просмотре профиля в поле поиска автоматически вбивается user:%USERID%.

Например, для [USERID = 182750](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A182750%20is%3Aa%20isaccepted%3A1) сейчас находятся 22 принятых ответа.

Если убрать условие `isaccepted:1`, то получится количество всех ответов (46). Так можно вычислить КПД (~48%).

### Через SEDE

Данные всех сайтов сети Stack Exchange выкладываются в [Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE)](https://data.stackexchange.com) примерно каждую неделю. Через SEDE к ним можно писать запросы.

Например, вот [запрос для определения соотношения принятых ответов заданного участника](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/1019989/accept-rate-by-user):

```
DECLARE @UserId int = ##UserId##
SELECT
  @UserId AS [User Link],
  s.answers_count,
  s.accepted_count,
  s.accepted_count * 1.0 / s.answers_count
FROM (SELECT
  COUNT(1) AS answers_count,
  SUM(CASE
    WHEN q.id IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE 1
  END) AS accepted_count
FROM posts a
LEFT JOIN posts q
  ON a.parentid = q.id
  AND q.posttypeid = 1
  AND a.id = q.acceptedanswerid
WHERE a.posttypeid = 2
AND a.owneruserid = @UserId) s
```

В качестве параметра он принимает ID участника, его можно получить из URL профиля. Например, для [ID 182750](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/182750/xelanimed) отображается КПД ~44% (20 принятых ответов из 45):

```
╔════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════════╦══════════════╗
║ User       ║ answers_count ║ accepted_count║ accept_rate  ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════╣
║ XelaNimed  ║            45 ║            20 ║        0.444 ║
╚════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════════╩══════════════╝
```

По сравнению с поиском отображаются устаревшие данные, но преимущество SEDE в том, что можно писать запросы ко всей базе пользователей.

Например, есть [запрос, который выводит лидеров среди участников по КПД](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/865295/users-with-highest-accept-rate-of-their-answers). При этом отсеиваются ответы на собственные вопросы и есть возможность установить минимальное количество ответов.

Так, среди участников, которые дали не меньше 100 ответов сейчас лидирует [@overthesanity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/303477/overthesanity) с КПД 86%. Среди людей со 100%-м КПД лидируют по количеству ответов [@martiliones](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/324018/martiliones), [@Gaket](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/253584/gaket) у которых по 7 ответов (еще отображается [@Сергей Мишин](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/253584/gaket), но по нему за последнюю неделю данные изменились).

Можно вообще выгрузить [всех пользователей с КПД больше 0](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/1019996/) и посмотреть как изменяется показатель в зависимости от количества ответов и выделить участников с относительно высоким КПД:

[image: Все пользователи]

Ожидаемо, КПД с количеством ответов балансируется: с ростом количества ответов диапазон КПД участников сужается. Это распределение лучше видно если отобрать пользователей, которые дали менее 150 ответов:

[image: Меньше 150]

Здесь КПД несколько отличается, т.к. не учитываются ответы на свои же вопросы.

### Средний балл за ответ

Не сразу обратил внимание, что в вопросе спрашивается про репутацию. Репутацию, заработанную на ответах оценить достаточно сложно, т.к. в начислении репутации есть много нюансов: разная стоимость плюсов и минусов, премии, вики-ответы, ограничение в 200 баллов за сутки, баллы за засчитанный ответ.

Качество ответов можно (грубо) оценить по среднему баллу по всем ответам пользователя. Аналогично, можно выгрузить [средний балл по всем пользователям](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/1020151/average-answer-score-for-all-users) и рассмотреть тренды:

[image: Средний балл (не меньше 10 ответов)]

Видно, что несколько выделяются из толпы [@SergeyTeplyakov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178188/sergey-teplyakov) (55 ответов со средним баллом 9,33) и [@NickVolynkin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/181472/nick-volynkin) (424 ответа со средним баллом 5,57).

Отдельно рассмотрим пользователей с меньшим числом ответов.

[image: Средний балл за ответ (не больше 100 ответов)]

### Средний балл за вопрос

Для полноты картины можно собрать аналогичные данные по [среднему баллу заданных пользователем вопросов](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/1020199/average-question-score-for-all-users) (из-за ограничений выгружаем пользователей, которые задали хотя бы два вопроса):

[image: Средний балл за вопрос от 20]

[image: Средний балл за вопрос до 50]

Среди участников, которые задали один вопрос лидирует [@Ivan43](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/197777/ivan43) с вопросом [Что делает код int main(){[](){}();}](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477156/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-int-main) (51 голосов).

Возможно, кто-нибудь с лучшими познаниями в анализе данных чем у меня сможет улучшить запрос, чтобы отсеять случаи когда средний балл сильно сдвигается засчет одного-двух заплюсованных вопросов.